# RubyMotion >> How to make a POST?

Tags: rubymotion

I've been checking out RestKit and the GET works

```
@client.get("/?amount=5", delegate:self)
```

Does anyone know how to make a POST and receive the result?

The docs mention that it looks something like this -

```
@client.post("/ask", params:@paramvar, delegate:self)
```

What do you encapsulate @paramvar? I have tried it as an array, hash and even nil - however, none of them have yielded any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an example in the RubyMotion_Cookbook.

https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_8/06_sendinghttppost

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
    @window.rootViewController = RootController.new

    url_string = "http://rubymotion-cookbook.herokuapp.com/post"
    post_body = "bodyParam1=BodyValue1&bodyParam2=BodyValue2"

    url = NSURL.URLWithString(url_string)
    request = NSMutableURLRequest.requestWithURL(url)
    request.setTimeoutInterval(30)
    request.setHTTPMethod("POST")
    request.setHTTPBody(post_body.to_s.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    queue = NSOperationQueue.alloc.init

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request,
      queue: queue,
      completionHandler: lambda do |response, data, error|
        if(data.length > 0 && error.nil?)
          html = NSString.alloc.initWithData(data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
          p "HTML = #{html}"
        elsif( data.length == 0 && error.nil? )
          p "Nothing was downloaded"
        elsif(!error.nil?)
          p "Error: #{error}"
        end
      end
    )


    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the bubble wrap library. It includes some really nice HTTP helpers.

http://bubblewrap.io/

Comment: The latest BubbleWrap has removed the already-deprecated BW::HTTP library. Use AFMotion now.

Answer (score 0):

Source:
https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap

Insallation:-
in console run 'gem install bubble-wrap' or mention 'gem bubble-wrap' in Gemfile

Line to be added in 'app_delegate.rb'file(by this Bubblewrap api is available through out app):-
require 'bubble-wrap/http'

Sample code for syntax:-
BW::HTTP.get("https://api.github.com/users/mattetti", {credentials: {username: 'matt', password: 'aimonetti'}}) do |response|
  p response.body.to_str # prints the response's body
end